# respond_to format.html too few arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a add bibliography form, I create an add author form that adds an author using json.

This works fine.

However, when the author gets added to the database, I want to show a success message.

This is my code:

```
def create
    @auteur = Auteur.new(params_auteur)
    respond_to do |q|
        if @auteur.save
            format.html{ redirect_to @auteur, notice: 'Auteur added successfully.'}
            format.js{}
            format.json{
                render json: @auteur, status: :created, location: @auteur
            }
        else
            format.html{ render action: "new"}
            format.json{ render json: @auteur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
    end
end
```

Then I added a file `views/auteurs/create.js.erb` that contains this code:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @auteur) %>").appendTo(".bloque_ajoute_auteur");
```

The error message I get is generated right after the (successful) insert of the new author into the database:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
ArgumentError (too few arguments):
app/controllers/administration/auteurs_controller.rb:23:in `format'
app/controllers/administration/auteurs_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
app/controllers/administration/auteurs_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Line 21 is the beginning of the respond_to block; line 23 is `format.html{ redirect_to @auteur, notice: 'Auteur ajouté.'}`

I thought I had pretty closely followed this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code ends up invoking the [format instance method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) of Kernel, instead of using the argument passed to `respond_to` block which is what should happen.

This method expects more arguments which are obviously not being provided in this case.

To solve the problem, change the argument name from `q` to `format`.

Answer (score 9):

It should be `respond_to do |format|`. As soon as it reaches the first instance of `format` without it declared, it will fail.

Comment: That's correct !! Silly mistake of mine. However, no message at all get sent back by this function (nothing in the server log nor in firefox development tools).